# Video recording from a webcam

Tags: video, webcam, recording

I need to record video from my webcam. I found the one solution in youtube that provides some tools for this matter, but it doesn't give a good quality of video. So maybe there're some better tools I can use, or it's cause my webcam isn't good enough (ASUS laptop webcam). Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like to use [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Record-from-a-Webcam), I hope it will help you as much.
You can see that he does not use third party software so you can make sure the quality of your camera will be at maximum resolution.

Comment: tank you a lot. Debut is really usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Try VirtualDub. It's free and has lots of features; it might not be the easiest software to use, though.

http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net